# SDL_Surface* as a constructor argument in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, sdl

I have a bit of a problem passing a SDL_Surface* to a class constructor, and then use it for rendering it. The class in question is similar to the following:

```
class Entity{
public:
    Entity(int posX, int posY, int width, int height,SDL_Surface* surf);
    SDL_Surface* getSurface();
private:
    int x,y;
    int w,h;
    SDL_Surface* entSurface;
}
Entity::Entity(int posX, int posY, int width, int height,SDL_Surface* surf){
    x=posX;
    y=posY;
    w=width;
    h=height;
    entSurface=surf;
}
SDL_Surface* Entity::getSurface(){
    return entSurface;
}
```

and I use it like this

```
SDL_Surface* surface=new SDL_Surface();
surface=loadBMP("path/to/img.bmp");

Entity someEntity=Entity(0,0,10,10,surface);
```

Program compiles and runs no problem but the following **DOESN'T** render the entity:

```
while(Running){
    //render(SDL_Surface* destination,SDL_Surface* src,int x,int y);
    //render() is a function that blits the surface
    render(theWindow,someEntity.getSurface(),0,0);
}
```

But this renders just fine

```
while(Running){
    render(theWindow,surface,0,0);
}
```

So what I'm wondering is why my pointer isn't passed to the class like I want it to. I'm very new to the concept of pointers but I don't understand why the address cant be passed like this.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** Requested by comments to show loadBMP

```
SDL_Surface* loadBMP(char* File) {
    SDL_Surface* Surf_Temp = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* Surf_Return = NULL;

    if((Surf_Temp = SDL_LoadBMP(File)) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Surf_Return = SDL_DisplayFormat(Surf_Temp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Surf_Temp);

    return Surf_Return;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Made it more clear what wasn't working

Comment: That seems like it should work, though you're doing a couple of dangerous/unrecommended things here.  You're creation Entity as a temporary and then assign someEntity to its value.  It should copy the pointer value into the someEntity but copying this way could cause problems with non-POD values.  Also, you create a pointer to SDL_Surface and overwrite surface's value when you call loadBMP.  If you want to change surface as part of loadBMP, you should pass the pointer in.  Otherwise, the original surface will leak.

Comment: Does `Entity` have *Destructor*, copy constructor ?

Comment: Please post the implementation of `loadBMP()`

Comment: @Jarod42 No it does not, is that relevant do the SDL_Surface* issue?

Comment: @Vinbot Ok, so how would you go about adding a new entity? In my full code I have a vector of smart pointers of type Entity that I store it in, but I still init them this way. Full code here: [link](https://github.com/Marcusandreas/ToTheStars) if you're interested. I see what you're saying with the new SDL_Surface* then overwriting it. I guess better to just set it as NULL then loadBMP() to it?

Comment: @olevegard Edited it in the OP

Comment: Can you precisely define what **doesn't work** means ? Compile error, wrong result ?

Comment: @Chnossos Sry for being unclear, it compiles just fine but the entity isnt rendered. Will edit OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. My problem was that my surfaces was initialized AFTER I initialized the entities, which meant the pointer was still NULL. Swapped it around and it worked!